# "when" + conditional sentence + tense

Tags: grammar, conditionals

> 1: She said she would do it when she came home.
>   2: She said she would do it when she comes home.

Which is correct, and why?

Comment: They're both correct. In the first one, you're setting the time for when she was talking, so the past tense is reported speech. In the second, the time is in the future, so the present tense is fine.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response John!
Just to make sure I'm following your reasoning: The first sentence implies that that "she" has come home already, while the second sentence implies that "she" has not yet come home. Is this correct?

Comment: For a more elaborate answer, try ell.

Comment: "ell" is a sister site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), in case you were wondering.

Comment: @J.R. Thanks :) I eventually figured it out, but I appreciate the clarification.

Comment: @Kris: I appreciate the suggestion, but I'm actually native (albeit confused) speaker :)

Comment: @Anonymous: Speaking for myself, I'm glad you didn't post it on ELL. Quite apart from the question of whether "when" associates with what she actually said, or *the time at which she said it*, I'm having a bit of trouble myself deciding which of the 4 permutations (*comes/came*, reported *before/after* she returns) are credible.

Comment: @Anonymous: It's perfectly alright for a native speaker to ask a question on ELL. If a question is more likely to appeal to an English learner (and aren't we all learners – even if we've been speaking English for decades) as opposed to the serious linguist, then that question might find a better home on ELL than on ELU. This question could fit in either place, but ELL is new enough that many new users aren't aware of its existence, and appreciate the pointer.

Comment: @J.R.: As per my comments, I find this one quite tricky, and I don't see that either of the two existing answers have covered all aspects of what's going on here. I think this is probably a bit complex for ELL.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Notice that I haven't taken a stand either way (and don't plan to). It wasn't my recommendation initially; I was merely clarifying Kris' comment. My follow-on comment simply makes it clear that native speakers shouldn't feel overqualified to ask a question on ELL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Her actual words were ‘I’ll do it when I come home’, and she meant that she’d fulfil some obligation or other on her return. When someone else says what she said, it becomes, in a rather formal style, ‘She said she would do it when she came home.’

‘She said she’d do it when she comes home’ says the same thing in a rather less formal way. Even less formal is ‘She said she’ll do it when she comes home.’

Comment: Of course, given OP's reported speech #1, it's equally possible her actual words were just *"I'll do it"*, said *at the time of coming home*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: That's definitely an interpretation I had not initially considered. It's interesting how ambiguous a sentence can be without context!

Comment: @Barrie England: Thank you for distinguishing between the formal and informal variations! If "she" said that she would do it and if I were merely providing further context as to when "it" would be done and if "she" has not yet come home, would the following still be correct: "She said she would do it when she came home."?  Or would "She said she would do it when she comes home" be more formal? I know I may be splitting hairs, but this would be useful to know in the event that I would need to put this down in writing. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Barrie,Anonymous: Putting aside the informality of *she'd*, I don't really see any formal/informal distinction between *when she **comes/came** home*. Surely the only difference is that with *comes*, we know for sure *she hasn't got home yet*, whereas you could use *came* before or after she returned.

Comment: ...personally, I'm sure I'd always use *comes* if she's not yet back, and *came* afterwards. And I'm pretty sure no-one would use *comes* after she was back, but I'm not really sure whether anyone would use *came* before she'd returned (unless they didn't actually know whether she was back or not).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Just to add one more twist: ‘She said she’d do it when she comes home’ **might** mean she engaged to [make her bed, do the breakfast washing-up, whatever] when she comes home from school every day, rather than before departing for school. AND ‘She said she’d do it when she came home—but then she never came home, so it’s still undone.’

Comment: @StoneyB: The unresolved question for me is: would anyone use *came* (if the intended sense is that's *when* she'll do it), if they know perfectly well that she's not yet back? I now think I would even say that myself, ***if*** I had reason to suspect she either wasn't ever coming home, or that she wouldn't honour her undertaking for some other reason.

Comment: @Anonymous. _She said she would do it when she came home_ would be the correct answer to an examination question which asked candidates to put _She said ‘I’ll do it when I come home’_ into indirect speech. That’s why I said it was formal. In practice, various combinations might occur, might, indeed, be more likely to occur, and that is why I said that the alternatives were less formal. But it’s difficult to draw any real conclusions about such matters in the abstract. The only way to be sure is to collect and analyze a corpus illustrating the various forms.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, both are considered correct, it really just depends on what you want to say.

In (1) the action is presumed to be 100 % complete, and it is in the past. However, the sentence is a bit ambiguous and leaves the possibility open to the idea that the action may still not be done.

In (2) the statement was made in the past, but it refers to a future event by using the present tense. The present tense is pretty useful, because it can also refer to future events, like in your example.

Comment: I don't agree there's any reason whatsoever to presume the "coming home" in #1 is "in the past". It's the construction that's 100% ambiguous; both interpretations are equally valid, and with no other context, equally likely.

Comment: @FumbleFingers and Patrick: Thank you for your responses! It's quite interesting to see how such a simple statement can be interpreted in so many differing ways by so many qualified people!